# convert string to datetime in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string strDate that contains selected date.

strDate holds value in the given format- month(3 letters) dd,yyyy

example 1: Feb 22, 2011

example 2: Jul 19, 2011

How can i convert this string value into datetime format of c#?

Comment: What should be the output format

Comment: @Dorababu - the output is a `DateTime` object.

Comment: @Dorababu. I want to convert into datetime type

Comment: Chris i know that is there any specified format like i am asking or just as datetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx). Try using:

```
DateTime.Parse(yourDateString, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: i would use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")`, cause you won't need a clone (new object) of the culture each time.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime myDateTime;

if (DateTime.TryParse(myDateString, out myDateTime) == True)
{
  // successfully converted to date time
}
```

If you wrap it in a check of DateTime.TryParse then if there is a case where the string isn't of a correct DateTime format then an exception won't be thrown.

This way you can place an else statement of change to == False and respond to the failed parse. (instead of having to deal with en exception).

Comment: I think that you are missing an `=`'s.  But, then again, the comparison isn't necessary :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "Jul 19, 2011";
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "MMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // the parsing was successful
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "MMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string myDateTimeString;

myDateTimeString = "19 Feb,2008";

DateTime dt;dt = Convert.ToDateTime(myDateTimeString);

Response.Write(dt.Day + "/" + dt.Month + "/" + dt.Year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx